# Visual Studio 2008 (C++) memory leak detection not showing file/method location - how to get that to work?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, memory-leaks

I am using the [instructions found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3(VS.80).aspx) to try to find memory leaks in a Win32 application.  As described, I put the

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
```

Lines at the top of a file (the cpp file that contains WINAPI _tWinMain) and then at the exit point of winmain I added

```
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
```

Unfortunately I do not see the line numbers/locations for the leaks (but I do get a list of leaks).

I also tried putting

```
_CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF); 
_CrtSetReportMode ( _CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);
```

at the beginning of winmain - and again, no luck.

I find this odd because I usually have had no problems ever finding leaks or having them reported automatically.

This is a huge, old legacy app I am working on for a new employer.  In the past I have worked from the standard VS wizard.

Any suggestions on how to get source lines/methods that are causing the leaks?  (or at least the lines for the "new" calls?

EDIT:

[I also tried visual leak detector](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/visualleakdetector.aspx) - with no success.

Very strange.

EDIT

I tried using the redefinition of new as listed below, however I get errors when boost is compiled in.

Comment: try deleaker. it should help you.

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure the code that's leaking is using the CRT debug allocation routines?  That requires using `malloc()` or `new` (as opposed to `LocalAlloc`, `GlobalAlloc`, some custom block allocator, etc..) and that `_DEBUG` (I think) must be defined when the CRT headers were included.

In order to get source lines for leaks, you will need to define [`DEBUG_NEW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz7sxz99%28VS.80%29.aspx) everywhere the allocations occur.  This is because in order to track them, each allocation must be replaced with a call that includes `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`.  The standard definition from the wizard looks something like:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#define DEBUG_NEW new(_NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
```

This doesn't handle `malloc`, there's probably a similar incantation for that, if the code you're debugging uses `malloc` instead of `new`.

If you're using pre-compiled headers, you can just put this in the precompiled header file and it will affect all the source files in that project.

Comment: Yep, not using globalalloc.  This is very strange to me.  I'll try adding the redef of new and see what happens.

Comment: I thought this would solve my problems, but when compiling the boost stuff in the project it chokes.  I guess I will have to separate out the boost issues somehow.

Comment: I've run into that as well.  Some boost libraries override `operator new`, and so you have to do the `DEBUG_NEW` definition *after* including boost headers, or at least some of them.

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't the workaround...  OK, nothing left to do but roll up the sleeves then.  Thanks

Comment: Now I think I know why this was removed...  Someone added boost to the project and took out the debug_new I guess.  I can't see why else it would not be there.

Answer (score 1):

Given a list of leaks at the end of the run, something like:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{12913} normal block at 0x000002BC648BB9D0, 82 bytes long.
 Data: <h t t p : / / a > 68 00 74 00 74 00 70 00 3A 00 2F 00 2F 00 61 00
{12912} normal block at 0x000002BC648B8030, 24 bytes long.
 Data: <0  d      `     > 30 CD 89 64 BC 02 00 00 D8 02 60 E5 F7 7F 00 00
...
```

It is easy to find where these memory blocks were allocated using `_CrtSetBreakAlloc` for example for stop when allocation with  allocation number `12913` happens one has to put

```
...
_CrtSetBreakAlloc(12913);
...
```

somewhere in code before the allocation happens: beginning of the unit tests or main-function are some possible examples. Now, `void* __CRTDECL operator new(size_t const size)` will throw an exception when block  with  allocation number `12913` is allocated and from the call-stack in debugger it is easy to find where the allocation did happen.

Comment: sorry for asking after years.. what about if allocation number is not static and gets changed every time when rerun?

Comment: @Zrn-dev Then first you need to eliminate this randomness (I know easier said than done), otherwise you need other tools (like valgrind).